# When working with sessions, timestamps are not added

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm working with the latest mongoose version of today (6.2.7) and I'm having a really weird bug.

This is my Schema:

```
const testSchema = new Schema<ITestSchema>({
  age: Number
}, { timestamps: true });

const testModel = model<ITestSchema>("test", testSchema);
```

When I'm creating new collections out of it  everything is working perfect! and I'm getting timestamps (updatedAt and createdAt) added to the collection.

**But** When I'm working with sessions the timestamps are not added and i see only "age", "_d" and "__v".

This is the example code for the creation with the sessions:

```
const test = async () => {
    const session: ClientSession = await mongoose.startSession();

    try {
        session.startTransaction();

        const newTest = new testModel({
            age: 30,
        }, { session });

        await newTest.save({ session });

        await session.commitTransaction();
    } catch (error) {
        await session.abortTransaction();
        throw error;
    } finally {
        await session.endSession();
    }
};
```

I tried read the doc several times and searched for similar issues online but could not find any.

Thanks 3>

Answer (score 0):

i know the question is old but i just came across this and found a solution, you mistake is that you are using session in 2 different places both when creating the model and when saving, the thing is if you use session only on testModel it also won't work, so the session must only be used when calling save function

sample code:

```
const modelObject = {
    '_id' : new Types.ObjectId(),
    ...dto
}

const newItem = new this.model(modelObject)

return newItem.save({
    session
});
```